# Python Regex Matching Partial Parentheses ONLY

Tags: python, regex

I have some poorly formatted text that I need to filter. As such, there are plenty of cases in which a quote in the text begins in one line and then cuts off and finishes in a second line. In such a case, my preference is to just remove the partial quotes completely, BUT, I want to preserve regular full quotes. I know that this can be done iteratively with a counter, but I would really prefer to go about it with Regular Expressions.

Take fore example:

```
"This is a quote"
This is an end "partial-
quote" Here is more text.
This is an end "partial-
quote w/o more text"
This is an "embedded" quote
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/78) is an example with my current attempt  `(\"[^\"\n]+?|^[^\"\n]+?\")(\n|$)`  Note that it fails in two circumstances:

1. Line 3 -- a partial quote proceeds the rest of a sentence (very rare occurrence, so if we can't solve its not the end of the world).
2. line 6 -- an embedded quote. This is a major problem and the main reason I have taken to SO with my problem. It grabs the last quote in the embedded quote to the end of the line.

I figured that I could set up an if statement and run each line through, checking if it has less than two quotes and then proceeding to parse the partial quotes, but I thought the minds at SO would have a much cleaner solution.

**NOTE** The desired output is:

```
"This is a quote"
This is an end 
 Here is more text.
This is an end 
This is an "embedded" quote
```

(I handle the whitespaces later-on)

Comment: Maybe you can check out the regex I proposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go,

```
^((?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")*[^"\n]*)"[^"\n]*\n[^"\n]*"(\n|)
```

Replace the matched characters with `\1\n`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/80)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''"This is a quote"
This is an end "partial-
quote" Here is more text.
This is an end "partial-
quote w/o more text"
This is an "embedded" quote'''
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?m)^((?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")*[^"\n]*)"[^"\n]*\n[^"\n]*"(\n|)', r'\1\n', s)
>>> print(m)
"This is a quote"
This is an end 
 Here is more text.
This is an end 
This is an "embedded" quote
```

Use this regex, if you want to deal with more than one lines present inside between double quotes.

```
^((?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")*[^"\n]*)"(?:[^"\n]*\n)+[^"\n]*"(\n|)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/81)

Comment: Sorry, I just started to play around with this. Is it possible to make it not rely on a closing quote? I.e. this wont work: https://regex101.com/r/tQ4oW4/1

Comment: oh, it has odd number of double quotes.. It can't be possible.

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind. I guess you can't really know which partial it is. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't rely on a closing quote then how could you know which quote ends?

Comment: @andoni i think this  https://regex101.com/r/tQ4oW4/2 would work for the missing double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps use this regex:

```
"[^"\n]+?\n[^"\n]+?(?:"|$)\s*
```

and replace with `\n`.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL3gR9/1)

`"[^"\n]+?\n[^"\n]+?` will match only the partial quotes (ensures there's a line break between the quotes).

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/PnHrhY)

Answer (score 1):

```
("[^"\n]*")|"[^"]*(\n)[^"]*"(?![^\n]*")|"[^"]*\n.*?(?=\n[^"]*"[^\n"]*")
```

You can try this.This will take case of odd number of quotes as well.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dL7oF8/6

Comment: @andoni you can try this with odd number of `"` as well